# how to place a scrolling image behind a stationary image in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to port an artificial horizon app I wrote for a PC in c# to swift. It has a bezel image which does not move and behind it is a horizon image which can move up and down behind the bezel. The "window" part of the bezel is yellow so in c# I just made the yellow opaque.

In swift I stated with the horizon inside of a UIScrollView but I'm not sure how to get that to work with a second image that should not scroll.

Not all that up to speed on this swift stuff, can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

```
let view: UIView = UIView.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 500, height: 500))
let scrollView = UIScrollView.init(frame: view.bounds)
view.addSubview(scrollView)
let backImage: UIImage = fromColor(UIColor.redColor(), size: CGSize(width: 1000, height: 1000))
let backImageView: UIImageView = UIImageView.init(image: backImage)
scrollView.addSubview(backImageView)
scrollView.contentSize = CGSize.init(width: backImage.size.width, height: backImage.size.height)

let frontImage: UIImage = fromColor(UIColor.blueColor(), size: CGSize(width: 100, height: 100))
let layer: CALayer = CALayer.init()
layer.frame = CGRect.init(x: view.center.x - 50, y: view.center.y - 50, width: 100, height: 100)
layer.contents = frontImage.CGImage
view.layer.addSublayer(layer)


func fromColor(color: UIColor, size: CGSize) -> UIImage {
  let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height)
  UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size)
  let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
  CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, color.CGColor)
  CGContextFillRect(context, rect)
  let img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
  UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
  return img
}
```

fromColor is a helper method.

Result of the code

[image]

Comment: It taken me a while to get back to this and realize it's not what I am looking for. This is just one image moving behind another one, no part of the image in the front image is transparent. Imagine the blue square in the red square is a single image. What I want is to have a second image scroll up and down within the blue space. I essentially I have an image of a frame and an image of a horizon, I want the image of the horizon to move up and down behind the frame.